# How to move to the end/beginning of the window/screen line?

Tags: window, motion

For example, I got a small window, a long whole line is split into multiple lines, not actually split, but with one arrow at the end of each line of the window, if I use C-e or End key, this will move end point to the end of this actual line.

`(setq truncate-lines nil)`is set in my init.el, how can I move my point to the end of the window/screen line?

Answer (score 3):

You want `visual-line-mode`. You can enable it with <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>visual-line-mode</kbd>.

See the EmacsWiki on:

- [Visual Lines](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VisualLineMode)
- [Line wrapping](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/LineWrap)

See the GNU Emacs manual on:

- [`visual-line-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visual-Line-Mode.html)

Comment: No, I don't want to enable `visual-line-mode`, I just want the whole line that way in Emacs, I already find the solution, I can use beginning/end-of-visual-line.

Comment: Okay then, post it as an answer and wait for answer-own-question time limit.

Comment: For anyone who may be interested to know, enabling `visual-line-mode` remaps `move-beginning-of-line` to `beginning-of-visual-line`; and `move-end-of-line` to `end-of-visual-line`.  For those who prefer that whole words not be broken up at widow-edge, `visual-line-mode` offers a wonderful built-in alternative.  This is also ideal for anyone with a word-processing background.

Answer (score 3):

I already find the solution, I can use `beginning/end-of-visual-line`

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-e") 'end-of-visual-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-a") 'beginning-of-visual-line)
```

Now, use C-S-a/e to do that motion.